# Is there a way to download shared files in Google Drive using their APIs?

Tags: google-drive-api

I have files that have been shared with a Google Drive account that I can then access and download via the Google Drive APIs and display to a user in a browser.
This has been working happily for the last few years.

Since the new shortcuts were introduced, the call I make to the API is no longer working for shared docs.

If I use the files->export call I get a 400 error "The requested conversion is not supported".

If I try the files->get call I get a 403 error "Only files with binary content can be downloaded. Use Export with Docs Editors files.".

The ability to download the content of a shared file was working up until the changes were made to introduce shortcuts.

Does anyone know of a method to use Google APIs to download contents of shared/shortcut files that are shared with my account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- The target file of the shortcut is Google Document.
- You want to export a Google Document from a shortcut file.

#### Issue and workaround:

In the current stage, unfortunately, it seems that the Google Document of the target of the shortcut cannot be directly exported from the shortcut file. By this, when the shortcut file is exported with `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{fileId of your shortcut file}/export?mimeType=application%2Fpdf`, an error like `The requested conversion is not supported.` occurs. And, when the shortcut file is downloaded with `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{fileId of your shortcut file}?alt=media`, an error like `Only files with binary content can be downloaded. Use Export with Docs Editors files.` occurs.

In this case, in order to export the Document from the shortcut file, I thought that it is required to run the following process.

1. Retrieve the target file ID from the shortcut file.
2. Export the retrieved target file ID.

When this flow is reflected in a curl command, it becomes as follows.

#### 1. Retrieve the target file ID from the shortcut file.

In this case, ["Files: get"](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get) is used. As a sample fields, `id,mimeType,name,shortcutDetails` is used. `shortcutDetails` returns the information of the target file.

```bash
$ curl \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer {your access token}' \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{fileId of your shortcut file}?fields=id%2CmimeType%2Cname%2CshortcutDetails'
```

When this command is run, the following valur is returned.

```json
{
  "id": "{fileId of your shortcut file}",
  "name": "filename",
  "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.shortcut",
  "shortcutDetails": {
    "targetId": "{fileId of your Google Document file}",
    "targetMimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.document"
  }
}
```

By this command, you can retrieve `"targetId": "{fileId of your Google Document file}"`.

#### 2. Export the retrieved target file ID.

In this sample, the Document is exported as PDF data. Here, please use the target ID. This ID is the file ID of Document.

```bash
$ curl \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer {your access token}' \
   -o sample.pdf \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{fileId of your Google Document file}/export?mimeType=application%2Fpdf'
```

By this command, the exported Document is saved as a PDF file.

#### Reference:

- [Files: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get)

Comment: Using the Google Client/Google Drive v3 library, I call 

files->get($fileid, ['fields' => 'id,name,size,mimeType,modifiedTime,shortcutDetails']);

However I don't get a shortcutDetails method in the response. I could try just using curl but have never had to use an access token previously. The API does not seem to have a call to "get access token". Once I work out how to retrieve an access token, I will try curl.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Joey Perroni Thank you for replying. About `Using the Google Client/Google Drive v3 library, I call files->get($fileid, ['fields' => 'id,name,size,mimeType,modifiedTime,shortcutDetails']);`, I cannot understand it. Can I ask you about the detail of it? Because in your tag, only `google-drive-api` is used and also I cannot find the language you are using in your question. So, I proposed an answer using the sample curl command. I think that this is due to my poor English skill. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your current situation? By this, I would like to modify it.

Comment: I am using the Google API library in PHP:
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-downloads

Comment: @Joey Perroni Now, I noticed that your comment has been updated. I cannot understand `However I don't get a shortcutDetails method in the response.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it? About `I could try just using curl but have never had to use an access token previously.`, if the file is publicly shared, I think that API key can be used instead of the access token. How about this?

Comment: @Joey Perroni And, from `I am using the Google API library in PHP: developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-downloads`, I could know you were using googleapis for php. I would like to modify my answer.

Comment: File is not publicly shared, it is shared with my account only. Previously I could get content of the file but as Google have now made them shortcuts the get/export methods no longer work. You explained it well in your answer.

Comment: @Joey Perroni Thank you for replying. If you are using `$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);`, I think that you can retrieve the access token from `$cliend` using `$accessToken = $client->getAccessToken()["access_token"];`. Is this useful? And, about `File is not publicly shared, it is shared with my account only.`, in this case, I think that the access token is required to be used. And, if you need a sample script of my proposed flow using googleapis for php, please tell me.

Comment: You're a champion. Thanks so much. The targetId is the key. I don't know where you found that information but I thank you for your help.

Comment: @Joey Perroni Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too. When a new shortcut is created using [Files: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create), `"shortcutDetails": {"targetId": "###"}` and `"mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.shortcut"` is required to be included in the request body. From this situation, I could know it.

Comment: @Joey Perroni As an important point, in the case of "Files: get" in Drive API v3, when `shortcutDetails` is not included in the values of `fields`, `shortcutDetails` is not returned. Please be careful about this. For example, if you want to retrieve all values, you can also use `*` as `fields`.